# How does the kubernetes apiserver handle etcd being down?

Tags: kubernetes

Im planing to migrate from etcd2 to etcd3. I've researched and come to this conclution

- change listen port so apiserver cannot write
- upgrade all nodes to etcd3
- use etcdctl migrate to migrate the data
- use cluster/images/etcd/attachlease/attachlease.go to attach TTL to /registry/events
- change back to correct listening port

However i would like to know what happens during the time apiserver cannot talk to etcd. Does the pod scheduling work etc?

Answer (score 0):

The control plane is down during an etcd outage (scheduling is also down). Pods that are already scheduled continue running and Services also continue to work.

**I suggest extensive testing before doing this in production.**